# Convert linear curve to exponential or logarithmic.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, logarithms, exponential-function

I currently work with a linear curve with a starting point at (0,0) and an end point at (100,100). The need arose to convert the points of the linear curve into an exponential or logarithmic curve. The red curve of the figure is the one currently used, I need to transform it into the blue or black curves. I would like to create two generic functions that do this conversion. I don't know how to do this yet, I will probably have to work with $y = log (x)$ and $y=a*b^x$, but the problem is that for any curve created, the start and end points must remain the same as the linear curve.[image]

Comment: $y=100\cdot (x/100)^a$ for various $0<a$ fit your picture very well.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Perfect. I tested it and it worked as I wanted. Thank you.